# Why cant I select on my inner table?

Tags: sql, select, db2

I don't understand why I can do this:

```
SELECT YEAR(CREATION_TIME) AS y, MONTH(CREATION_TIME) as m, COUNTRY_CODE
FROM PRODUCTS INNER JOIN COMPANIES
ON COMPANIES.COMPANY_KEY = PRODUCTS.CUSTOMER_ID
WHERE CREATED_BY IN ('VOLVO','SAAB')
```

But not

```
SELECT y FROM
(
    SELECT YEAR(CREATION_TIME) AS y, MONTH(CREATION_TIME) AS m, COUNTRY_CODE
    FROM PRODUCTS INNER JOIN COMPANIES
    ON COMPANIES.COMPANY_KEY = PRODUCTS.CUSTOMER_ID
    WHERE CREATED_BY IN ('VOLVO','SAAB')
)
```

I get the following error:

> Error: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601,
>   SQLERRMC=;;CORRELATION NAME, DRIVER=3.53.70 SQLState:  42601
>   ErrorCode: -104 Error: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-514, SQLSTATE=26501,
>   SQLERRMC=SQL_CURLH200C1, DRIVER=3.53.70 SQLState:  26501 ErrorCode:
>   -514

My end goal however is to do something like:

```
SELECT y, m, COUNTRY_CODE, count(*)
FROM
(
    SELECT YEAR(CREATION_TIME) AS y, MONTH(CREATION_TIME) AS m, COUNTRY_CODE
    FROM PRODUCTS INNER JOIN COMPANIES
    ON COMPANIES.COMPANY_KEY = PRODUCTS.CUSTOMER_ID
    WHERE CREATED_BY IN ('VOLVO','SAAB')
)
GROUP BY y, m, COUNTRY_CODE
```

Comment: Don't know about db2, but try to give an alias for your subquery. Something like SELECT y FROM(...) as T

Comment: Side note - grouping by extracted year and month this way will ignore indices.  Joining to a virtual/permanent calendar table may result in better performance (and eliminate the need for wrapping this portion of the query).  Permanent calendar tables are ridiculously useful for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be running a really old version of DB2. At some point a correlation name was required for subselects, so try this:

```
SELECT t.y FROM
(
    SELECT YEAR(CREATION_TIME) AS y, MONTH(CREATION_TIME) AS m, COUNTRY_CODE
    FROM PRODUCTS INNER JOIN COMPANIES
    ON COMPANIES.COMPANY_KEY = PRODUCTS.CUSTOMER_ID
    WHERE CREATED_BY IN ('VOLVO','SAAB')
) AS t
```

Comment: Worked fine, thanks. Answer goes to you. So close @TimBiegeleisen ;)

Comment: He may also be on z/OS. Even in version 11, you must have an alias. They don't like change on the Mainframe...

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax in the second query is incorrect.  You can't reference a column alias without also referencing the table.  This should work:

```
SELECT t.y FROM
(
    SELECT YEAR(CREATION_TIME) AS y, MONTH(CREATION_TIME) AS m, COUNTRY_CODE
    FROM PRODUCTS INNER JOIN COMPANIES
    ON COMPANIES.COMPANY_KEY = PRODUCTS.CUSTOMER_ID
    WHERE CREATED_BY IN ('VOLVO','SAAB')
) AS t
```